# How to add WHERE statement to this SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add a where statement to this query so it only shows records that have been set as published.

```
$query = "SELECT id, heading, summary, date, keyword1, keyword2, keyword3
     FROM " . DB_TABLE . "";
```

I've tried

```
$query = "SELECT id, heading, summary, date, keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, publish
     WHERE publish ='y' FROM " . DB_TABLE . "";
```

And

```
$query = "SELECT `id`, `heading`, `summary`, `date`, `keyword1`, `keyword2`, `keyword3`, `publish`
   WHERE `publish` ='y' FROM " . DB_TABLE . "";
```

But none of them seem to work, any help greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: **`SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...`**

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm

Comment: Really? can't even be bothered to look up the actual docs, instead of trying to come up with your own (wrong) syntax? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
$query = "SELECT `id`, `heading`, `summary`, `date`, `keyword1`, `keyword2`, `keyword3`, `publish` FROM " . DB_TABLE . " WHERE `publish` ='y' ";
```

If you look at [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) you will see that `SELECT` statement comes first, then is `FROM` statement and `WHERE` comes last. Of course there are various other statements that can be used, you can find all them in the link above

Comment: Ah I see, excellent, thank you for your help :)